# How to output all users , not just one in the ASP NET CORE WEB API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

string connect = "Server=localhost;port=51363;Database=Click;Uid=root;pwd=root;charset=utf8";

```
[HttpGet("get_userBase")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser()
{
    string name = "";
    var mysqlConnect = new MySqlConnection(connect);
    await mysqlConnect.OpenAsync();
    var command = "SELECT name FROM Click";
    var mysqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(command, mysqlConnect);
    var mySlAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlCommand);
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    await mySlAdapter.FillAsync(dataSet);
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            name = dataRow[i].ToString();
        }
    }

    await mysqlConnect.CloseAsync();

    var listUser = new List<User>
    {
        new User(name, "efer", "123", "123", 0)
    };

    return Ok(listUser);
}
```

The problem is that all users come to the name, but they are not all output, but only the last one is output, I tried through cycles, but the result only multiplies them, please help me what am I doing wrong

Comment: 1. It is not C only C# which makes a maaaasive difference.

Comment: forgot to finish writing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
name = dataRow[i].ToString();
```

You overwrite the `name` so it holds the last one only.